# how to integrate particles js in laravel 5.6 as background in login system

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.6, particles.js, login-system

In Laravel 5.6 I want to put particles.js as background for login system . how can I integrate particles.js in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You can install it using the terminal with the command

```
npm install particles.js
```

Then just include it into the app.js file in your resources/assets/js folder, like this:

```
window.particlesJS = require('particles.js');
```

After that you can just use it normally in your project, like you would use vue, which already comes pre-installed.